# If $f$ and $g$ are continuously increasing functions, then prove that $(f∘g)$ is also increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-writing, function-and-relation-composition

I am studying for my real analysis class, and one question involves two increasing functions $f$ and $g$. I have already proven that if $f$ and $g$ are increasing, then so is ($f+g$), and that the product ($fg$) is not necessarily increasing.

The third part that I am working on asks about the composition ($f∘g$). My thoughts are that plugging one increasing function into another increasing function would mean their composition is also increasing. Here is what I have:

Let $a<b$. It follows that $g(a) < g(b)$. Applying $f$ to both sides, we have $f(g(a))<f(g(b))$.

Is this proof sufficient?

I apologize if this question has been already answered as I imagine it has - but I could not find the proof. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is sufficient.

Comment: @theideasmith they are not given $f,g$ are differentiable

Comment: Yes...my mistake.

Comment: It looks good to me!

Comment: @theideasmith  That is not a general proof since we are not given anything regarding the smoothness of $f$ or $g$.

Comment: I would not use the phrase "Applying $f$ to both sides".  Instead, I think you should say: Since $f$ is increasing, we may conclude that $f(g(a))<f(g(b))$.

Comment: Depending on your definition of increasing, it might be that you should change all $<$ into $\leq$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the proof is good, let me recap, maybe it helps a bit.

We must prove that if $a<b$ then $(f\circ g) (a) < (f\circ g)(b)$.

Using the definition of composition this is equivalent to $f(g(a))< f(g(b))$.

We have: $a<b \implies g(a)< g(b)$ because $g$ is increasing, and we have $g(a)< g(b)\implies f(g(a))<f(g(b))$ because $f$ is increasing.

---

Notice that we did not use the fact that $f$ or $g$ are continuous. Although if we used it we could have proved that $f\circ g$ is continuous.